# Creating a dynamic “storage_data_disk” block for Azure VM in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

Within AzureRM, one or more Storage data disk(s) can be created empty and attached to the VM, e.g.:

```
variable "extra_disks" {
  type = list(object({
    name              = string
    disk_size_gb      = number
    managed_disk_type = string
    lun               = number
  }))
  default=[]
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "linuxvm" {
  name                  = var.vm_name 
  location              = var.location
  resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name

  ...
  dynamic "storage_data_disk" {
    for_each = var.extra_disks 
    content {
      name              = storage_data_disk.value.name
      disk_size_gb      = storage_data_disk.value.disk_size_gb
      managed_disk_type = storage_data_disk.value.managed_disk_type
      lun               = storage_data_disk.value.lun
      caching           = "ReadWrite"
      create_option     = "Empty"
    }
  }
...
}
```

And I can define an array to create extra_disks dynamically, e.g. in terraform.tfvars:

```
extra_disks = [
  {
    name              = "data1" # logs, backup, etc.
    disk_size_gb      = 40
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
    lun               = 0
  }
]
```

I can also attach existing managed disks while creating a VM. In this case the data structure would be something like this:

```
variable "extra_disks" {
  type = list(object({
    name              = string
    #disk_size_gb      = null # existing data
    #managed_disk_type = null # existing data
    lun               = number
  }))
  default=[]
}
```

The parameters such as disk_size_gb and managed_disk_type would not be relevant in this scenario.

```
extra_disks = [
  {
    name              = "db-data-opt-03-manageddisk" 
    disk_size_gb      = 0 #this will not be used 
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS" #this will not be used 
    lun               = 0
  }
]
```

And with the following terraform code, I can perform a lookup query:

```
data "azurerm_managed_disk" "data_disks" {
  for_each            = var.extra_disks
  name                = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}
```

Is there a way to create a dynamic block that can be used to support both these types of storage configurations?

What I have tried is the following:

```
variable "attach_existing_managed_data_disks" {
  default = 0
} 

dynamic "storage_data_disk" {
    for_each = var.extra_disks 
    content {
      name              = (var.attach_existing_managed_data_disks == 0 ? storage_data_disk.value.name:  
        data.azurerm_managed_disk.data_disks[*].id)
      disk_size_gb      = (var.attach_existing_managed_data_disks == 0 ? storage_data_disk.value.disk_size_gb : null)
      managed_disk_type = (var.attach_existing_managed_data_disks == 0 ? storage_data_disk.value.managed_disk_type : null)
      lun               = storage_data_disk.value.lun
      caching           = "ReadWrite"
      create_option     = (var.attach_existing_managed_data_disks == 0 ? "Empty" : "Attach" )
    }
  }
```

The problem is how should I map the name to associate with the data values returned in the query of data_disks while attaching existing managed disks?

```
      name              = (var.attach_existing_managed_data_disks == 0 ? storage_data_disk.value.name:  
        data.azurerm_managed_disk.data_disks[*].id)
```

Here is the error I am currently getting:

on ../terraform-azurerm-vm/main.tf line 61, in data "azurerm_managed_disk" "data_disks":

[image]

The reason is that I am creating 3 VMs using the same module and not all of the VMs have extra_disks.

The following code with count parameter would not work, as we can't have count and for_each in the same code block:

```
data "azurerm_managed_disk" "data_disks" {
  #count = var.attach_existing_managed_data_disks == "" ? 0 : 1

  for_each            = var.extra_disks
  name                = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}
```

If I can resolve these issues, not sure if the code block with "data_disk[*].id" would correctly index the data disks in the dynamic block:

```
    name = (var.attach_existing_managed_data_disks == 0 ? storage_data_disk.value.name:  
    data.azurerm_managed_disk.data_disks[*].id)
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin I have updated my question to include the errors with additional comments.

Answer (score 0):

> Creating a dynamic “storage_data_disk” block for Azure VM in Terraform.

> I have followed [GithubDoc](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/6082) as a reference to create a **Azure VM** with `dynamic storage data disk` and acttached to same **VM** using below terraform code.

> ```
> provider "azurerm" {
>   features {}
> }
> resource "azurerm_resource_group" "venkatrg" {
>   name     = "demo-rg"
>   location = "westus2"
> }
>
> resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
>   name                = "vm-vnet"
>   address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
>   location            = azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.location
>   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.name
> }
>
> resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
>   name                 = "vm-subnet"
>   resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.name
>   virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
>   address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
> }
>
> resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
>   name                = "vm-nic"
>   location            = azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.location
>   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.name
>
>   ip_configuration {
>     name                          = "internal"
>     subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
>     private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
>   }
> }
>
>
> resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm-dbnode" {
>   name                          = "sample-vm"
>   location                      = azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.location
>   resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
>   primary_network_interface_id  = azurerm_network_interface.nic.id
>   network_interface_ids         = [azurerm_network_interface.nic.id]
>   vm_size                       = "Standard_D8s_v3"
>   delete_os_disk_on_termination = "true"
>
>   storage_os_disk {
>     name              = "vm-os-disk"
>     caching           = "ReadWrite"
>     managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
>     create_option     = "FromImage"
>     disk_size_gb      = 64
>   }
>
>   storage_image_reference {
>     publisher = "SUSE"
>     offer     = "sles-sap-12-sp5"
>     sku       = "gen1"
>     version   = "latest"
>   }
>
>   dynamic "storage_data_disk" {
>     iterator = disk
>     for_each = range(5)
>     content {
>       name                      = join("-", ["data", "disk", disk.key])
>       caching                   = "None"
>       create_option             = "Empty"
>       managed_disk_type         = "Standard_LRS"
>       disk_size_gb              = 512
>       write_accelerator_enabled = false
>       lun                       = disk.key
>     }
>   }
>
>   os_profile {
>     computer_name  = "venakt-vm"
>     admin_username = "Admin"
>     admin_password = "Pa$$word@123$"
>   }
>
>   os_profile_linux_config {
>     disable_password_authentication = false
>   }
> }
> ```

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]

Once the **Terraform** code is run, a `virtual machine` is created with five  `512GB data disks`, which are also attached to the `VM`

[image]

Comment: Thank you Venkat. However the problem I am having is to create a Terraform VM module that is flexible (without code duplication) to create data_disks as you have shown in your example, as well as, read data elements of already created data disks and allow them to attach to the VM I am creating.  ```data "azurerm_managed_disk" "data_disks" {
  for_each            = var.extra_disks
  name                = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}```

Comment: You can use resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" block to attach existing managed disk to VM,refer this link for more details: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment